# Can we use the alternating series test here ??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose the series $a(n)x^n$ has finite radius of convergence $R$  and $a(n) >0$ for all $n$ .Show that if the series converges at $R$ , then it also converges at $-R$.
My solution:since the series $a(n)R^n$ converges ,then we have $\lim a(n)R^n =0$ , hence by the alternating series test the series $a(n)(-R)^n =$ series $a(n)R^n (-1)^n$ converges ....Is this proof correct or do I need to show something is deceasing as well. If the proof is correct why do not I need to show decreasing ??

Comment: No, since the alternating series test requires the terms are (eventually) decreasing, which is may not be the case here.

Comment: Well you can just use the idea of absolute convergence. If a series converges absolutely then it converges.